# “How to export other next file‘ after 2000 rows data

Tags: php

I am using PHP for export CSV file this is working, but i export 2000 or greater rows how to create automatic next CSV file.

How to Move other file on after 2000 rows?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = records.csv');
echo $header = "Name";
echo  "\r\n";
$sql = mysql_query(“Select * from table”);
while ($getData = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   echo '"'.$name.'"';
   echo  "\r\n";
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Put a where condition. `where id > 2000`

Comment: Check the count of rows and divide by 2000 if its above to 2k. put divided answer in loop to create that number of files

Comment: You should consider moving away from the `mysql_` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_chunk` function to keep the records of 2000 and export them in csv.

For example

```
$rowData = [
    [1,2,3],
    [11,21,31],
    [21,22,32],
    [31,42,73],
    [111,222,333]
];
foreach(array_chunk($rowData, 2) as $key => $records){
   $file_name = 'export_data_'.$key.'.csv';
   writeToCsv($file_name,$records);
}
//funtion to export data to csv
function writeToCsv($fileName, $rowData){
    $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');
    foreach ($rowData as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
   fclose($fp);
 }
```

In your case use `array_chunk($rowData, 2000)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$rowLimit = 2000;
$fileIndex = 0;
$i = 1;
$handle = null;
$fileList = array();
$timestampFolder = strtotime("now").'/';
mkdir($timestampFolder);

$sql = mysql_query("Select * from table");
while ($getData = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    if( ($i%$rowLimit) == 1) {
        $fileIndex+=1;

        if(!is_null($handle)) {
            fclose($handle);
        }

        $fileName = "records".$fileIndex.".csv";
        $handle = fopen($timestampFolder.$fileName, "a");
        $fileList[] = $fileName;


    }

    fputcsv($handle, $getData);
    $i++;
}

foreach($fileList as $file) {
    echo '<a href="'.$timestampFolder.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br>';
}
```